# How to simulate XHR request in Scrapy for dynamically loading web pages?

Tags: python, ajax, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to crawl olx.in site `http://www.olx.in/newdelhi/bmw/`, I have set this URL as `start_url`.

Now to go to next page as it is not normal HTML but it dynamic so in network tab I saw that next button creates a XHR request with `POST` method. Now I have to simulate it in request method(I guess...) but I can't figure out what will be it's parameters.

I am new to python and web-scraping so sorry if it's too general but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at `FormRequest` that enables you to send data via HTTP POST. As you can see the next button creates a request to `http://www.olx.in/ajax/newdelhi/search/list/`, with some form data. Just populate the `formdata` parameter with the needed values from the current `Response` object. As you are trying to build a pagination you should check [this page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/intro/tutorial.html#following-links) on how to do it properly.